# Wait for AlertDialog in infinite loop

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, wait

I am currently working on a simple mobile game in Android Studio and got the following problem:

When the player starts a battle with an enemy, an infinite loop is executed (which only ends when the player reaches 0 health).
In this loop i want to Display an AlertDialog (and do some other stuff like attack calculation), the loop should continue when the AlertDialog is dismissed.
How can I implement this functionality?

This is my (simplified) code:

```
while (player.hp > 0) {
    showDialog("some Text");
    .
    .//wait for AlertDialog to close?
    .
    do_other_stuff();
}
```

showDialog(String text):

```
    AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    ad.setCancelable(false);
    ad.setMessage(text);
    ad.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ad.show();
```

*I made (copy-pasted) the showDialog() method only because I use AlertDialogs very often, i could also do it without writing an method for it if only possible this way...*

**EDIT:**
I tried a different approach for this problem without a while-loop, everything works fine now.
I'm checking the player's HP after every action that can reduce health.

Comment: You start by replacing the infinite loop with some alternative implementation of game logic that works in a more flexible, event-driven manner.

Comment: It is unclear what is the problem with your code? Does the dialog not show up? Does the loop stop?

Comment: well nothing happens and then the screen turns black. i think because it doesn't wait for the button to be pressed it creates an infinite amount of alert dialogs? could this be?